# how to make C to C payments using paypal in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal

I am new to PayPal, can anyone help me ?
I am developing an application where customer will pay to another customer and we are using PayPal. how it can be possible in rails?

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

I think it would helps you:

1) [Guide](https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/mktg/docs/buy_now_button_guide_112012.pdf)

2) [Rails casts for PayPal notif](http://railscasts.com/episodes/142-paypal-notifications)

3) [PayPal API usage guide](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/)